# Admob failed to load ad message "No ad config"

Tags: android, admob, ads

Admob failed to load ad message "No ad config" and status error code: 3 . One week before, real Ads are displayed correctly. But now onwards, My test ads were working but real ads are not displayed instead it shows Error message "No ad config".

After , I updated with app-ads.txt , this problem arises. Please help me with this issue

Log Message for your reference:
D/Ads: {
"Code": 3,
"Message": "No ad config.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null",
"Response Info": {
"Response ID": "null",
"Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
"Adapter Responses": [],
"Response Extras": {}
}
}

Comment: whats is your Build Compile SDK Version?

Comment: compile SDK version :  32

Comment: check in  policy center of Admob if they shows any issue there?

Comment: No issues in admob policy center. its is working fine one week before but from today on, the real ads are not shown

Answer (score 0):

Generate a signed a bundle/apk and test. I had the same issue and this worked for me. Adding the test device id may also work. - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. same noAdconfig error only came .